# PHP SQL "Protect" string

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I've made a PHP script ectracting xml values and inserting them into a SQL DB.

However these strings have all kind of signs, backslash, %, *, ', etc. And usally i end up with an error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL        server version for the right syntax to use near 's demanding business environment. 
Product Lin' at line 2
```

I have tried a few things like "stripslashes" etc. Bu i cant seems to find the commaned to "protect" the variable for interfering with my SQL.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to use PDO. Not only will it solve your issues but it will make your script much more secure from injection attacks.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

PDO documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using old `mysql_query()` system you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` before inserting a string into your SQL for escaping string. Like this :

```
$myStringEscaped = mysql_real_escape_string($myString);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting down. Would be nice if they left a message....I guess this forum is for helping each other ?. Thanks for the help all :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the PHP mysql module, then

```
 $escaped_string = mysql_real_escape_string($your_variable);
```

should do the trick.

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

(If you're using PDO or MySQLi, the relevant links are there too)